# Get a directory path with console-like behaviour

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am developing a non-GUI application for Linux. At some point I ask the user to input a directory path, which will be used to store files.

It there a way to have behaviour similar to the console (eg. when pressing `TAB`, the path is automatically filled for you, or available directory paths are printed)?

[image: TAB example]

What is the usual solution for this kind of problem, in case what I am looking for doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual solution is to [use readline's completion facility](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_48.html), just like the shell does.

Comment: Argh I was just a bit too late ! XD

Comment: Notice that `readline` is a library licensed under GPL, so your code needs to be GPL licensed also.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [readline library](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_48.html)